# Make usb stick bootable while keeping files

Tags: boot, usb, usb-flash-drive

I am learning how to install an image on my USB stick and make it bootable using the rufus software. But, I only have USB sticks with data, and want to keep them there. Is it possible to somehow install the OS image and make the USB stick bootable while keeping the existing partition and the data on it?

PS: don't want to resize the partition either, that's risky operation.. just wonder if there's an option where the image can be installed within an already established partition.

Answer (score 1):

It is *possible* to do so, but **most likely**, any utility used to create a bootable USB drive, such as [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) or [UNetbootin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/), or Microsoft's [Media Creation Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d) will **destroy** that data.

If you want that data on the USB along with the files created by the USB creation tool, there are a few ways to do so.

- First, **save all the files on the USB to another location**.
- Create the bootable USB, which will almost certainly format it. Either:

  - Create the media with using the utility's default settings, without [persistent storage](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/), *or*
  - Create the media with [persistent storage](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/).
- Examine the *Properties* of the USB stick to see if it still has sufficient room for all the old files. If not, then there's not space to do anything more.
- *If there's sufficient space*, either

  - Copy the saved files to a new folder in the USB's main partition, or,
  - For a device with persistence, copy the files to a folder in the partition for persistent data.

In some cases, where the file system is checked for consistency before boot (e.g., newer versions of Ubuntu), adding files to the root directory may prevent booting.